Traefik is not applying the routing rules even though they are parsed correctly
I have Traefik installed on a virtual Debian server. I am not using Docker or Kubernetes. I am using it to route traffic to various other servers that are also running on the same physical server under different virtual machines. In particular, I am currently working on installing a GitLab server under Ubuntu. When I try to connect to the server through the URL, I get an internal server error. However, when I connect directly to the server with the IP and my browser, it works.
Here is what the Traefik log shows when I try to connect:


{"ClientAddr":"162.158.137.230:43484","ClientHost":"162.158.137.230","ClientPort":"43484","ClientUsername":"-","DownstreamContentSize":21,"DownstreamStatus":500,"Duration":5572119,"OriginContentSize":21,"OriginDuration":5523512,"OriginStatus":500,"Overhead":48607,"RequestAddr":"gitlab.DOMAIN","RequestContentSize":0,"RequestCount":2392,"RequestHost":"gitlab.DOMAIN","RequestMethod":"GET","RequestPath":"/favicon.ico","RequestPort":"-","RequestProtocol":"HTTP/1.1","RequestScheme":"http","RetryAttempts":0,"RouterName":"gitlab@file","ServiceAddr":"192.168.0.5:443","ServiceName":"gitlab@file","ServiceURL":"https://192.168.0.5:443","StartLocal":"2024-11-10T16:38:36.53410902-06:00","StartUTC":"2024-11-10T22:38:36.53410902Z","entryPointName":"web","level":"info","msg":"","request_User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","time":"2024-11-10T16:38:36-06:00"}



Something that I notice is that even though I am using the https protocol, the log says that I am connecting through the "web" entry point instead of the "websecure" entry point. I am not sure why this is.
Here is my static config:


global:
  checkNewVersion: true
  sendANonymousUsage: false

providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/conf.d/
    watch: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      caServer: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      email: "MYEMAIL"
      storage: /etc/traefik/ssl/acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"

  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: "MYEMAIL"
      storage: /etc/traefik/ssl/acme.json
      tlschallenge: true

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

log:
  filePath: /var/log/traefik/traefik.log
  format: json
  level: INFO

accessLog:
  filePath: /var/log/traefik/traefik-access.log
  format: json
  filters:
    statusCodes:
      - "200"
      - "400-599"
    retryAttempts: true
    minDuration: "10ms"
  bufferingSize: 0
  fields:
    headers:
      defaultMode: drop
      names:
        User-Agent: keep



And here are my two relevant dynamic configs:


http:
  routers:
    catchall:
      entryPoints:
        - "web"
        - "websecure"
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/`)"
      service: unavailable
      priority: 1

  services:
    unavailable:
      loadBalancer:
        servers: {}

tls:
  stores:
    default:
      defaultGeneratedCert:
        resolver: cloudflare
        domain:
          main: DOMAIN
          sans:
            - "*.DOMAIN"
            





http:
  routers:
    gitlabsec:
      rule: Host(`gitlab.DOMAIN`)
      entrypoints:
        - "websecure"
      tls:
        certResolver: cloudflare
        domains:
          - main: "gitlab.DOMAIN"
      service: gitlabsec

    gitlab:
      rule: Host(`gitlab.DOMAIN`)
      service: gitlab

  services:
    gitlabsec:
      loadbalancer:
        servers:
          - url: https://192.168.0.5:443
            scheme: https
        passHostHeader: true

    gitlab:
      loadbalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://192.168.0.5
            scheme: http
        passHostHeader: true



My certificate for DOMAIN and *.DOMAIN are being generated. One for gitlab.DOMAIN is not, but I am assuming that traefik is just using the *.DOMAIN cert for gitlab.DOMAIN.
Any help or direction to look would be appreciated.

Why do you double all the routers/services? Usually you would have a central http-to-https redirect, then all services on https. Traefik will by default terminate TLS, you would always use the same internal protocol (http/https), independently of the external protocol used.
Maybe check simple Traefik example for some inspiration: https://github.com/bluepuma77/traefik-best-practice/tree/main/docker-traefik-dashboard-letsencrypt

Do you have examples that are not Docker? To me, trying to convert the Docker labels to the appropriate YAML for the configs is a winding mess. It isn't always clear what goes where.

There is also an example with dynamic config file: https://github.com/bluepuma77/traefik-best-practice/tree/main/traefik-external-forward
